# Unable to Pair Android IVI with Samsung Galaxy M32

Tags: python, java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to Pair and Unpair an Android based IVI Unit with an Android device (Samsung Galaxy M32) multiple times. Although it is pairing for the first time, all successive attempts, it is not able to pair. Below is the process I follow,

So these testcases are written in Python which is just calling an RPC (written in Java), which will do the main function of Pairing and Unpairing.

Setup class

1. preconditions()- Turning on BT in the Target (IVI Unit) and Mobile Phones. Below is the code for Preconditions (Note that the self.target refers to the IVI Unit)
   [image]

After the setup class, I am calling the Pair function, it will do the below functions,

1. unPairAllPairedDevices() - unpairs all paired devices one by one

   [image]
2. btGetRemoteDevice() - get the device id of the remote device  - need MAC address as the input

   self.target.gbs.btGetRemoteDevice(macAddress)
3. btCreateBond() - creates a bond between the target and the phone (returns True or False depending on the outcome)

   self.target.gbs.btCreateBond()
4. Tap on the popup on the phone - Once we get the pairing popup on the Galaxy M32

[image]

5. btSetPairingConfirmation() - set the pairing confirmation - returns True or False

   self.target.gbs.btSetPairingConfirmation(True)
6. Get the paired devices info

   Paired_info = self.target.gbs.btGetPairedDevices()

After Pairing is completed, I call the Unpair device function as below,

```
def unPairDevice(self,macAddress):
        self.target.gbs.btGetRemoteDevice(macAddress)
        self.target.gbs.btRemoveBond()
        sleep(5)
        Paired_info = self.target.gbs.btGetPairedDevices()
        logging.info(f"btGetPairedDevices {Paired_info}")
        # getting length of list
        length = len(Paired_info)
        logging.info(f"length>>>>> {length}")
        if length != 0 :
            # Iterating paired device list
            for i in range(length):
                if Paired_info[i]['Address'] == macAddress:
                    logging.info(f"Device still exists in list {Paired_info[i]['Name']}")
        else :
            logging.info(f"Device is unpaired successfully {macAddress}")
```

What it is doing is, getting the Remote device MAC address of the Bonded device, calling the RemoveBond method to remove the bond. then get the Paired device information.

So, it is working properly for the first pairing and unpairing process, but from the second try onwards, it is just not pairing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.